# I share memory in C between a main process and his children but I have trouble syncronising their actions

Tags: c, signals, semaphore

I have a program that is supposed to do this:

1. The main program creates a chunk of shared memory (to share with his future children) the size of a struct called ClientInfo which contains 2 integers and a string. Then the program asks the user for a number which is stored in the variable **n**
2. The main program creates **n** children.Then the children wait for a SIGUSR1 signal from their father.
3. The main program sends a SIGUSR1 signal to all his children.
4. Each child reads a string from the terminal, writes it in the shared memory and also increments in one unit both shared integers. Then he sends a SIGUSR1 to his father, sleeps between 1 and 10 seconds and then ends.
5. Each time the father recieves a SIGUSR1 it prints the contenent of the shared memory, then only ends when all of his children end.

The "catch" is that this is college homework and they told us that the father must be able to print the content of the shared memory **one time for each children, so n times in total**. Also we can't use sigwait() or global variables (unless global variables are the only way).

Also each time I run the program it just hangs indefinitely asfter asking for **n**

I know there must be some sort of race condition but I'm really bad at that and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SHM_NAME "/shm_example"
#define SEM1 "/example_sem1"
#define SEM2 "/example_sem2"

#define NAME_MAX 100


typedef struct{
    int previous_id; //!< Id of the previous client.
    int id; //!< Id of the current client.
    char name[NAME_MAX]; //!< Name of the client.
} ClientInfo;



int main(void) {

    int i,n,*pids;
    int fd_shm;
    int error;
    struct sigaction act;
    ClientInfo *example_struct;
    sigset_t mask, oldmask; 
    sem_t *sem_write = NULL,*sem_read = NULL;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigemptyset(&oldmask);  
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

    printf("Introduzca un numero:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(!(pids = malloc(n*sizeof(int))))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ((sem_write = sem_open(SEM1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((sem_read = sem_open(SEM2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    



    fd_shm = shm_open(SHM_NAME,O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); 


    if(fd_shm == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating the shared memory segment \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   
    error = ftruncate(fd_shm, sizeof(ClientInfo));

    if(error == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error resizing the shared memory segment \n");
        shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Map the memory segment */
    example_struct = (ClientInfo *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(*example_struct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_shm, 0);

    if(example_struct == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error mapping the shared memory segment \n");
        shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    (example_struct->previous_id)=-1;
    (example_struct->id)=0;



    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pids[i] == 0) {
            char nombre[NAME_MAX];
            srand(getpid() ^ (i * 1091));
            sigsuspend(&oldmask);
            sem_wait(sem_write);
            (example_struct->previous_id)++;
            printf("Introduzca un nombre:\n");
            scanf("%s",nombre);
            memcpy(example_struct->name, nombre, sizeof(nombre));
            (example_struct->id)++;
            kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
            sem_post(sem_write);
            sleep(1 + (rand()%10));
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }

    }
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
    kill(0,SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

    while(1){

    sigsuspend(&oldmask);


    /*if(wait(NULL)<0){
       sem_close(sem_write);
       sem_close(sem_read);
       sem_unlink(SEM1);
       sem_unlink(SEM2);
       munmap(example_struct, sizeof(*example_struct));
       shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }*/


    sem_wait(sem_read);
    sem_wait(sem_write);
    sem_post(sem_read);

    printf("El cliente es %s con id %d y el previo es %d\n",example_struct->name,example_struct->id,example_struct->previous_id);
    fflush(stdout);
    sigemptyset(&mask); 
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);

    sem_wait(sem_read);
    sem_post(sem_write);
    sem_post(sem_read);}

}
```

Comment: why don't you use semaphores for synchro?

Comment: @OznOg I forgot to put the code in my question (I'm very tired), now you can see the semaphores

Comment: why do you use signal instead of semaphores to "communcate" ?

Comment: @OznOg because the assignment says so, it specifies that the child must send SIGUSR1 to the father

Comment: in the end why do you have semaphores, then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

#define SHM_NAME "/shm_example"

#define NAME_MAX 100


typedef struct{
    char name[NAME_MAX]; //!< Name of the client.
} ClientInfo;


atomic_bool done = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

void child_handler(int dummy) {
    (void)dummy;
    done = true;
}

int main(void) {

    int i,n,*pids;
    int fd_shm;
    int error;
    struct sigaction act;
    ClientInfo *example_struct;

    printf("Introduzca un numero:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(!(pids = malloc(n*sizeof(int))))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_handler = child_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd_shm = shm_open(SHM_NAME,O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if(fd_shm == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating the shared memory segment \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    error = ftruncate(fd_shm, sizeof(ClientInfo));

    if(error == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error resizing the shared memory segment \n");
        shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Map the memory segment */
    example_struct = (ClientInfo *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(*example_struct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_shm, 0);

    if(example_struct == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error mapping the shared memory segment \n");
        shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pids[i] == 0) {
            /* Child */
            while (!done) {
                /* Wait for signal */
                sleep(1);
            }
            printf("child %d wakes up\n", getpid());
            sprintf(example_struct->name, "my pid is %d", getpid());
            kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
            sleep(1 + (rand()%10));
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    /* only father here */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        done = false;
        kill(pids[i], SIGUSR1);
        printf("Waiting child %d\n", pids[i]);
        while (!done) {
            /* Wait for signal */
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf("Answer from %d: %s\n", pids[i], example_struct->name);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

In the end, I don't really understand why you used semaphores if you  are asked to use signal only, thus I removed them. I also removed the id do get a less chatty code, you may add them back if you need it.

The point here is I perform the wait with a while() loop waiting for a boolean atomic variable.

So the father trig a signal on the first child, then waits for it to signal back, then do the same with the next one, and so on...

so you get such a sequence:

```
$ ./example
Introduzca un numero:
5
Waiting child 14314
child 14314 wakes up
Answer from 14314: my pid is 14314
Waiting child 14315
child 14315 wakes up
Answer from 14315: my pid is 14315
Waiting child 14316
child 14316 wakes up
Answer from 14316: my pid is 14316
Waiting child 14317
child 14317 wakes up
Answer from 14317: my pid is 14317
Waiting child 14318
child 14318 wakes up
Answer from 14318: my pid is 14318
```